# Sum up values in dictionary in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, sum

I have a dictionary with data for every 0,04 sec, looking like that

```
{1: 0, 2: 4.22109297745, 3: 0.324239117507, 4: 3.99972239616 ...}
```

keys represent time and values — data I received.
I need to count the arithmetic mean for every second. So first I have to sum up data from every 25 values. And here I'm stuck...
I would appreciate a lot some help.

Comment: python dict are unsorted btw, so looping as dict might not worked as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your dictionary contains keys 1 to 25 for the 1st sec, 26-50 for the 2nd etc which are inserted in a sequential way...
Assuming that, you could do the following
First make an ordered dictionary

```
    import collections
    od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

and then

```
    avg=[]
    sum = 0
    for k,v in od.iteritems():
        sum += v
        if k%25 == 0:
            avg.append(sum/25)
            sum = 0
```

By the end of the loop avg[0] will contain the average of the 1st second's values, avg[1] the average of the 2nd etc...
However this is going to work only if every second has exactly 25 values